# How energy is conserved when a body moves due to differential radiation emission?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, momentum, energy-conservation, doppler-effect

Suppose a body losing heat by radiation in the space, a white dwarf star for example.

After some time its content of energy decreases by the same amount of the radiation released.

But it is possible (as for example if half of the outer shell of the star has an lower emissivity than the other half), that the flux of radiation is greater in one direction than to the other. As radiation carries momentum, the star moves to the side of less radiation, acquiring kinetic energy.

The same released energy in the form of radiation results from the same decrease of the star energy. But in the second case, there is an additional kinetic energy term.

Is the Doppler effect the correct explanation for that difference? As the star moves, the average frequency changes for each side, and the released energy is lower in the second case, explaining the kinetic energy term.

But that explanation relates energy and frequency, which arises in quantum phenomena as the photoelectric effect. Is it also necessary to deal with E = hf for a classical macroscopic situation?

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming, simultaneously, two things that cannot be true at once:

- Both stars convert the same amount of energy from thermal energy per unit time, and
- Both stars emit the same amount of energy per unit time as electromagnetic radiation.

If you want the same thermal energy conversion rate, there will be different amounts of energy in the electromagnetic field in each case. If you want the same amount of energy in the electromagnetic field, there will be a different thermal energy conversion rate in each case.

Suppose we have two stars, one radiating isotropically and one not, that **convert the same amount of thermal energy**. For the isotropically-radiating star, all of the converted thermal energy ends up in the electromagnetic field. For the anisotropic star, it gains some macroscopic kinetic energy (distinguished from thermal energy since thermal energy is the kinetic energy of *random* motion while macroscopic kinetic energy is the kinetic energy of *nonrandom*, *correlated* motion), which means less energy is deposited in the electromagnetic field.

Now suppose we have two stars, one radiating isotropically and one not, that **emit the same amount of electromagnetic energy per unit time**. Since the anisotropic star deposits some of its converted thermal energy into macroscopic kinetic energy, it must convert thermal energy into other forms at a higher rate than the isotropic star in order to radiate the same electromagnetic power.

Comment: I mean the first option. It is easy to see that, due to the difference of emissivity, more energy will be released to one side, and momentum is conserved by the star movement. But why that movement could affect the total energy emission?

Comment: @ClaudioSaspinski The configuration (i.e. "shape") of the emitted electromagnetic field is different in the anisotropic case than in the isotropic case. This shape difference affects the amount of energy that is carried away by the field.